# How Do I Load Images From SD Card One At A Time?

Tags: android, image, sd-card

Ok, I am able to load a specific image into ImageView from my SD card...no problem. But I need to take a step further and add a button load the next image (move/copy/delete previous image). I can add the button, etc but how do I retreive the 'next' image without knowing filenames? Here is the code so far. I would have liked to use Gallery but it has been deprecated and I can't seem to make anything else work.  Thank You

```
package com.demo.ShowSDImages;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class AndroidBitmap extends Activity 
  {private final String imageInSD = "/sdcard/er.PNG";

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageInSD);
       ImageView myImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
       myImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can give a try to this sample here..[Check this link](http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/08/image-slide-show.html)

here i think the below code can help you in getting the images .

```
int imageCount = sdcardPath.listFiles().length;
  for (int count = 0; count < imageCount - 1; count++) {
     Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sdcardPath.listFiles()[count]
     .getAbsolutePath());
```

In the sample instead of using the thread or timer use the the same logic that is using of the showNext() in the button click event

Give a try. Happy Coding